# How can I map in JAVA with JACKSON an array from a JSON which can contain differently typed objects as items?

Tags: java, json, jackson, pojo

As you can see in the example below, the first item in the `attributes` array is an object consisting of two string properties. The second object consists of a string and array property. I would like to decode both of these types of JSON objects into a collection of Java objects.

How I can express this in a [POJO](https://www.quora.com/What-is-POJO-in-Java) java class to handle decoding JSON like this?

```
attributes:[
  {
    "attribute_code": "has_options",
    "value": "0"
  },
  {
    "attribute_code": "ewc_top_quick",
    "value": [
      {
        "label": "Display",
        "value": "12.5",
        "suffix": "''"
      },
      {
        "label": "Grafica Integrata",
        "value": "1",
        "suffix": ""
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Apparently I have done the question wrong, so the downvoting, I will delete it, but can I known why? I'm not a native english speaker,so I suppose my english is not good enough to pose a question here

Comment: How can it be more precise? There is only one question. How I can map a array with multiple type in it. 

Nothing more, just one question and has been partially answered and the response is focused on a single problem.

Why is not focused? There a single problem and a single question with a single technology. I have even shown an example with ONLY the single problem in the JSON.

Comment: Again the single question is: How can I map an array wich can contain either objects and string ?

Comment: I really need help on this I don't understand why this has been closed. Really disappointing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you can use `Map<String, Object>` fro this field.

```
class Attr {

    private String attribute_code;

    private Map<String, Object> value;
}
```

After this, you can work with this object.

Also, you can use `@JsonAnySetter`. It's something similar to the previous option.

And the best way to resolve your situation it's **custom deserializer**. I strongly recommended this option.

Comment: I don't think this will work, when the member is a string will not be set to a map

Comment: I think the easiest solution is to use:
List<Map<String, Object>> Attributes;  and then switch on type.

Comment: Yes. I think so.